# jquery automated twitter feed and api 1.1

Tags: jquery, api, twitter

I have an automated twitter feed on my site and it worked fine until recently, I have figured out its because of the changes to Api 1.1 and that I need to make changes but I am at a loss how to fix it! this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=75&callback=?&q=%2y' ,function         (data){
    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++){
        var tweeter = data.results[i].from_user;
        var tweetText = data.results[i].text;
        var tweetText = tweetText.substring(0, 139);
        tweetText = tweetText.replace(/http:\/\/\S+/g, '<a href="$&" target="_blank">$&</a>');
        tweetText = tweetText.replace(/(@)(\w+)/g, ' $1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
        tweetText = tweetText.replace(/(#)(\w+)/g, ' $1<a  href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
            $('#tw').append('<li class="tweet"><div class="tweetImage"><a                       href="http://twitter.com/'+tweeter+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+data.results[i].profile_image_url+'" width="48" border="0" /></a></div><div class="tweetBody">'+tweetText+'</div></li>');    
    }
   });

   function autoScroll() {
var itemHeight = $('#tw li').outerHeight();
    /* calculte how much to move the scroller */
   var moveFactor = parseInt($('#tw').css('top')) + itemHeight;
   /* animate the carousel */
   $('#tw').animate(
       {'top' : moveFactor}, 'slow', 'linear', function(){
           /* put the last item before the first item */
           $("#tw li:first").before($("#tw li:last"));
           /* reset top position */              
           $('#tw').css({'top' : '-6em'});
     });
  };
 /* make the carousel scroll automatically when the page loads */
 var moveScroll = setInterval(autoScroll, 6000);
});
```

works great, it pulls up tweets with the hastag jquery, but what I want is tweets by the username nnacanada, how can I acomplish this? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: i think all you need to do is add "&screen_name=nnacanada" to your getJSON call. $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=75&screen_name=nnacanada&callback=?&q=%2y'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the solution is bit complicated as we have to use https instead of http in api 1.1, and the solution is to use authentication https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you add &user_id or $screen_name to your URL with the proper value, it should work.